# Symfony 2: Howto Map 2 way multiple Entities with one FormType

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Suppose i have an Bundle to manage anything related to advertisements.
This bundle contains an Entity ***Advertisement***. this has an field for relation purposes: lets say ***relation*** field

Suppose i have an Entity ***Company*** and an Entity ***Events*** in different Bundles
*(In companies there are companies stored and in events there are events stored.)*

Case:
The entities have a relation to multiple Advertisements. 
A single Advertisement has a relation to only one of the entities.

From the perspective advertisement:

- I want to be able to select one of the entities (entity.id) to view or update the reference (like dropdown)

From the perspective of an event or a company:

- I want to be able to select/add/delete multiple advertisements (like the symfony collection form type)

all this preferred without the use of foreign-keys.

the entities are like "modules" so there can be more than just these entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to use *OneToOne* (For Advertisement) and *OneToMany* (For **Company** and **Events**) relations.

It's easy to use, read this doc : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html